# Possible to set width as auto in this?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

The first example shows what I'm trying to achieve.
But, I can't set a width to `.sub` because there might be new items added to `.sub`. Hence the width should increment accordingly.

But, without setting a width, the result is as shown in example 2.

Any ways to let `.sub` items grow while maintaining the horizontal layout?

```css
.wrap, .wrap2 {
  width: 100px;
}

.container {
  width:100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

.item {
  position:relative;
}

.sub {
  background: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  left:100px;
  top:0;
  width: 340px;
}
.sub li {
  display:inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 10px;
  &:first-child {
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    border-left:0;
  }
}

.wrap2 .sub {
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<h4>Example1. This is what I want. But, without setting width to .sub</h4>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li class="item item1">
        <a href="">hello</a>
        <ul class="sub">
          <li class="item item1">hello world</li>
          <li class="item item2">world hello</li>
          <li class="item item3">foo bar</li>
          <li class="item item4">bar foo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item item2">world</li>
      <li class="item item3">foo</li>
      <li class="item item4">bar</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<h4>Example2. This is what happens when no width is set to .sub</h4>
<div class="wrap2">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li class="item item1">
        <a href="">hello</a>
        <ul class="sub">
          <li class="item item1">hello world</li>
          <li class="item item2">world hello</li>
          <li class="item item3">foo bar</li>
          <li class="item item4">bar foo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item item2">world</li>
      <li class="item item3">foo</li>
      <li class="4item item4">bar</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set `display:flex` in your `.sub`

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100px;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
}
.sub {
  background: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 0;
  display: flex
}
.sub li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.sub li:first-child {
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h4>Example1. This is what I want. But, without setting width to .sub</h4>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li class="item item1">
        <a href="">hello</a>
        <ul class="sub">
          <li class="item item1">hello</li>
          <li class="item item2">world</li>
          <li class="item item3">foo</li>
          <li class="item item4">bar</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item item2">world</li>
      <li class="item item3">foo</li>
      <li class="item item4">bar</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** based on your updated question, you can use as others already pointed out `whitespace:nowrap`

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100px;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
}
.sub {
  background: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 0;
  white-space:nowrap
}
.sub li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.sub li:first-child {
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h4>Example1. This is what I want. But, without setting width to .sub</h4>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li class="item item1">
        <a href="">hello</a>
        <ul class="sub">
          <li class="item item1">hello world</li>
          <li class="item item2">world hello</li>
          <li class="item item3">foo</li>
          <li class="item item4">bar</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item item2">world</li>
      <li class="item item3">foo</li>
      <li class="item item4">bar</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried `display:flex` before actually. My previous example wasn't a good one, just updated it. The answer after you is perfect though :)

Comment: I've updated my answer tho due to your updated question

Answer (score 2):

You can just add:

```
.sub {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

This will force the contents to stay inline and disregard the width of the parent.

```css
.wrap,
.wrap2 {
  width: 100px;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
}
.sub {
  background: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.sub li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 10px;
  &: first-child {
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    border-left: 0;
  }
}
.wrap2 .sub {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<h4>Example2. This is what happens when no width is set to .sub</h4>
<div class="wrap2">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li class="item item1">
        <a href="">hello</a>
        <ul class="sub">
          <li class="item item1">hello</li>
          <li class="item item2">world</li>
          <li class="item item3">foo</li>
          <li class="item item4">bar</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item item2">world</li>
      <li class="item item3">foo</li>
      <li class="item item4">bar</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `white-space: nowrap` to your .sub.

```css
.wrap, .wrap2 {
  width: 100px;
}

.container {
  width:100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

.item {
  position:relative;
}

.sub {
  background: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  left:100px;
  top:0;
  width: 300px;
}
.sub li {
  display:inline-block;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 10px;
  &:first-child {
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    border-left:0;
  }
}

.wrap2 .sub {
  width:auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<h4>Example2. This is what happens when no width is set to .sub</h4>
<h4>and white-space:nowrap is added</h4>
<div class="wrap2">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li class="item item1">
        <a href="">hello</a>
        <ul class="sub">
          <li class="item item1">hello</li>
          <li class="item item2">world</li>
          <li class="item item3">foo</li>
          <li class="item item4">bar</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item item2">world</li>
      <li class="item item3">foo</li>
      <li class="item item4">bar</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```